# How do I tell SQL to run a command using another table as the input value?

Tags: mysql, sql, for-loop, mariadb

I'm trying to build a query that will show me the number of points for each team (as a start anyway) in my database. I have two tables, one with the list of teams, and one with the matches, in the format

Week|HomeTeam|AwayTeam|HomeScore|AwayScore|Result|MatchID

Where Result can be either A (away win), H (home win), or D (draw). I can find the number of points for a given team easily enough with

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(matches.Result)*3 FROM matches WHERE (HomeTeam='Arsenal' AND Result='H') OR (AwayTeam='Arsenal' AND Result='A')) +
(SELECT COUNT(matches.Result) FROM matches WHERE (HomeTeam='Arsenal' OR AwayTeam='Arsenal') AND Result='D');
```

I want to do is something like:

```
FOR EACH teams.Team in teams
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(matches.Result)*3 FROM matches WHERE (HomeTeam=Team AND Result='H') OR (AwayTeam=Team AND Result='A')) +
(SELECT COUNT(matches.Result) FROM matches WHERE (HomeTeam=Team OR AwayTeam=Team) AND Result='D');
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working and I can't quite figure out why. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Simple use a subquery:

```
SELECT teams.Team,
((SELECT COUNT(matches.Result)*3 FROM matches WHERE (HomeTeam=teams.Team AND Result='H') OR (AwayTeam=Team AND Result='A')) +
(SELECT COUNT(matches.Result) FROM matches WHERE (HomeTeam=teams.Team OR AwayTeam=teams.Team) AND Result='D')) as Points
```

Comment: For some reason I get:    ERROR 1109 (42S02): Unknown table 'teams' in field list. Despite having the table in the db: MariaDB [prem]> SHOW TABLES;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_prem |
+----------------+
| matches        |
| teams          |
+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: I ran a shorter statement to test and got the same error:      SELECT teams.Team, (SELECT COUNT (matches.Result) FROM matches);

Comment: OK, I got a statement to run, at least:     SELECT Team, (SELECT COUNT(Result)*3 FROM matches, teams WHERE (AwayTeam = teams.Team AND Result ='A') OR (HomeTeam =teams.Team AND Result ='H')) FROM matches, teams AS points;      This just brings up a table of 3000 rows, however, with the teams repeated over and over, and all the points are '324'.